# I am three, but I have thirteen

Tags: riddle

I am three, but I have thirteen.

I am also one, and then I have many millions.

But recently, I've been feeling like two.

How many stars are there?

(*Note: This puzzle was inspired by another puzzle on here asking about stars, which I can't seem to find right now, but it is unrelated.*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

> there are fifty stars

because

> you are the United States of America.

*I am three*

> Perhaps the letters U,S,A.

*but I have thirteen*

> Stripes on the US flag.

*I am also one*

> A single nation.

*and then I have many millions*

> People.

*But recently, I've been feeling like two*

> It is widely thought that the US is becoming more and more sharply divided along political lines.

Comment: Nice!  I had something slightly different in mind for the "three" clue (I was thinking of the flag being the answer, not the country) but this is close enough to earn the check mark.  Thanks for solving my riddle!

Comment: I also thought that it would be nicer for the flag rather than the country to be the answer, but I didn't (and don't) see why the flag is "three". "Stars / and / stripes", perhaps? (Also, it's definitely the country rather than the flag that has many millions.)

Comment: Red, white, and blue -- three colors.  For the "many millions" I was thinking you could say the flag has the citizens as followers, or maybe it has citizens since it represents the country?  Eh, live and learn (about puzzle design)!

Comment: Oh, colours. Of course. Silly me.